# Preliminary way to estimate damping quality factor (Q) from a SolidWorks FEM

Tags: finite-element-method, vibration, solidworks, modal-analysis

I am analyzing the modal response of a structural FEM for a spacecraft structures course. I'm using Solidworks Simulation Premium.  Need first mode to be above 40Hz and the damping Q-factor (quality factor) to be >=10.

I have had some trouble finding consistent nomenclature and information about the Q-factor on the web, but in case some one else has this question, but a few sources that I found to be at least partially helpful are as follows:

1. [https://vru.vibrationresearch.com/lesson/q-factor/#:~:text=The%20Q%2Dfactor%20measures%20the,harder%20it%20is%20to%20control](https://vru.vibrationresearch.com/lesson/q-factor/#:%7E:text=The%20Q%2Dfactor%20measures%20the,harder%20it%20is%20to%20control).
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor
3. https://faculty.uml.edu//pchowdhury/PHYS2690/Supp/Q-factor.pdf

I found number 3, in particular to be helpful.

So the question is this:  how can one get modal response peaks out of solidworks sim premium to estimate the Q-factor of a structure with the resonant peak frequency / half power bandwidth equation?  (see 1 and 3)?

$Q=\frac{Resonant Peak [Hz]}{Half power bandwidth [Hz]}$

This may be a bit of a over-simplistic question, but I really appreciate inputs here.

Thanks!
-Dave

[https://vru.vibrationresearch.com/lesson/q-factor/#:~:text=The%20Q%2Dfactor%20measures%20the,harder%20it%20is%20to%20control](https://vru.vibrationresearch.com/lesson/q-factor/#:%7E:text=The%20Q%2Dfactor%20measures%20the,harder%20it%20is%20to%20control).

Answer (score 0):

Linear FEA doesn't include damping. You need to explicitly add damping after you've got your FEA results. Typically this is done as a proportion of the mass or stiffness matrix. This is of course a lousy way to model a complex system.

I'm baffled why you'd want high Q in a structure.